# Plone: How to sort the navtree portlet using another list as base order?

Tags: sorting, plone

I have a navtree on a plone site, already using this configuration:

```
navigation = mapping['navigation']
navigation.includeTop = True
navigation.currentFolderOnly = False
navigation.topLevel = 0
navigation.setProperty('metaTypesNotToList', ['ATBooleanCriterion', ...(another types go here) ..., MemberDataContainer'])
navigation.setProperty('idsNotToList',['Members', 'events'])
```

This results in a NavTree portlet that lists me this links: (the information into () are the ids of the elements, the ones we use when we don't want navtree to show then, putting then on the `idsNotToList` variable under `navtree_properties`)

- Home (I think this id is /root , but someone help me here telling me what is the exactly id resulted from the option: `navigation.includeTop=True`)
- Help (/help)
- Search on bibliography (/searchbibliography)
- Statistics (/statistics)

Now what I want is sort this navtree using this another list (from ids) as pattern:

```
['root', 'searchbibliography', 'help', 'statistics']
```

so that NavTree order is exactly displayed as this given list order, showing me links like this:

- Home
- Search on bibliography
- Help
- Statistics

We see that there's no alphabetycal order here. There's exactly a specific order.

So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: 
The ID of the root page is `front-page`
I could solve this by doing under the installation of the product:

```
def install(portal):
    portal = getToolByName(portal, 'portal_url')
    portal = portal.getPortalObject()

    portal.moveObjectsToTop(['front-page', 'searchbibliography', 'help', 'statistics'])
    portal.plone_utils.reindexOnReorder(portal)
```

Ordering the `folder_contents` of my portal automatically ordered the navigation portlet (that uses the same order of the portal folder (i.e., folder_contents)).